# Meteor Urigo/meteor-ionic package. Difference between angular and angularMeteor?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework

I recently tried to port my project based on ionicframework to meteor using the Urigo/meteor-ionic package.

Based on [this example](https://codeload.github.com/netanelgilad/meteor-ionic-example/zip/master): it seems the runtime has access to both a `angular` and a `angularMeteor` variable. That last one is inserted through a global-imports.js file.

> angularMeteor = Package['urigo:angular'].angularMeteor;

Which one should I be using ? When is this line added to the global-imports.js file ?

Comment: Using for what? initializing the application?

Comment: Well you are using the `angularMeteor` variable [in one example](https://github.com/netanelgilad/meteor-ionic-example/blob/master/meteor-ionic-example.js) I'm wondering what is its purpose and if I am missing something not to use it. For example you are defining a controller with `angularMeteor.controller` instead of `angular.controller` why ?

Answer (score 1):

Controllers should be defined under the app's module.

This is the best practice and also how the angular-meteor examples work.

I've opened an issue in meteor-ionic to update the example:
https://github.com/netanelgilad/meteor-ionic-example/issues/3

Comment: Therefore there is no need for using `angularMeteor`, only `angular` should be used.